# Connection reset by peer w/ Python's Request Module. Curl and Postman work fine.

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

`Python 2.7.10`

I'm making a very basic API call to my gitlab repo.

I can successfully `curl` the endpoint and I can succesfully call it with `Postman`

However it fails when trying to use Python's request module.

**Curl Works:**

`curl https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects`

- Outputs the expected JSON response from the endpoint (no auth needed)

**Postman I also get the expected result:** 
[image: Postman call works]

**However when I submit via requests:** 
[Cert is self signed, hence the verify=False]

```
r = requests.get("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects", verify=False)
```

Error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./repo_analyzer.py", line 36, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/api/v4/projects", verify=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I'm a bit at a loss on why it's not working with python, but works otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a ton of blogs and posts about this, it seemed that I needed to update requests[security] package through pip.

I was getting errors running both `pip install -U requests[security]` and `sudo pip install -U requests[security]` so I started from scratch:

1. Downloaded Python 2.7 and reinstalled from the official site
2. `pip install requests`
3. `pip install -U requests`
4. `pip install -U requests[security]`

After that, the calls were successful.